# jQuery .animate() change top with bottom property

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am building a menu in jQuery using .animate() but I've run into a problem. I have a div that initially loads with position:fixed and bottom:30px. Upon click of a link, I want my div to move to the height position of that link. Essentially, I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wRjyK/32/

The problem is that the first animation initially moves from off of the top of the screen in a downward motion. (Because it doesn't have a top property) I want the animation to start with its current position. When I repeat the animation with other links, it looks fine because my div now has the proper top property to work off of.

A simple fix would be to change the css of my div to have a top property, but my design requires the bottom property. Any ideas?

Comment: For what it's worth, the first animation in your fiddle correctly moves the `<div>` upwards on Firefox 5.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that just a second ago. However, that is the only browser that I know of that works.

Comment: the demo on jsfiddle seems to work fine as it is (I used FF 5). which browser did you test it on?

Comment: Seems to work on FF 3.6 too. But not on Chrome 15.0.849.0 dev-m or IE8. (And Safari, I think. Not at my dev machine) Bug in jQuery perhaps? Or just browser incompatibility?

Comment: Works when I changed the css from bottom: 20px; to top: 400px in Chrome.  This may possibly be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986353/jquery-animate-bottom-problem

Comment: Problem is I can't use top. I will look into that other post though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few keys to making this work. Here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/sGNZ9/2/).

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var footerOffsetTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
    $('.footer').css({position:'absolute',bottom:'',top:footerOffsetTop})
        .animate({top:offsetTop},500);
});
```

It essentially works like this:

1. Find the footer's offset().top value
2. Change the footer's CSS so that it is absolutely positioned with the
   top: property having the value found in #1. This keeps allows you to
   animate it's top property, without having it jump.